# Query all subscribers that received specific amount of emails

Tags: email, query

I want to set a "limit" in terms of email sends, e.g. every contact that already received 3 mails within the last 3 days shall be excluded from a next mail. I tried with query but since it's not working I think I have a mistake in there - can anyone elaborate on how such a query should look like?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share a copy of your failed query?

Comment: Could you clarify whether you are working with Marketing Cloud (the tag is `marketing-cloud`) or with Sales/Service Clouds?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `_Sent` [data view](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sent.htm&type=5) and run a query in a daily automation within Automation Studio. The data column `EventDate` will give you the date that the email was sent (you can query the last 3 days) and you can exclude a rolling subscribers in a data extension to use as a suppression.